# Cannot read property 'visitExpression' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

In my angular app at the startup point I'm facing this error:

Cannot read property `visitExpression` of `undefined`

**What could be the problem?**

Comment: In my case the error was coming in test cases. I have added extra `,` in the begining of  component name: `MockComponent({selector: ',player'})`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In my case, it was components with empty selectors.

Comment: In my caste, there was two comma between 2 path.

Comment: in my case ```const routes: Routes = [, { ... }, { ... } ]```

Comment: in my case, there war 2 commas between two paths.

Comment: I came for same problem and found my comment

Answer (score 243):

In my case, it was duplicate `,` in the Routes array in `app.routing.ts`.

You can use `,[\s]*,` as a [Regular Expression search query](https://regex101.com/r/98FoEI/1) to find it in your routes to find two commas with (0 to many) white spaces in between them.

Comment: I had the same issue, I added a class to `canActivate:` and I added a comma `,` at the begining of the array by mistake: `[,RedirectLoginGuard, 'canActivateForLoggedIn'] `

Comment: i had the same issue, i had an  unwanted comma in app.roueting.module

Comment: Now you understand all the pain frontend developers feel

Comment: yup, same. Good thing we have stackoverflow :D

Answer (score 24):

It was ',' in my case in **app.module.ts** file.

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    **AppRoutingModule,,**
    HttpClientModule,
```

Changed it to:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    **AppRoutingModule,**
    HttpClientModule,
```

Answer (score 13):

For me it was ,, in the `*-routing.module.ts`

```
   path: 'shoplist',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('../shoplist/shoplist.module').then(m => m.ShoplistModule)
      }
    ]
  },, <------------------ this was the cause
  {
    path: 'notification',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('../notification/notification.module').then(m => m.NotificationModule)
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: We live in a world of AI and a compiler can't even tell us if there's an extra comma in the routing module. SMH. Thanks, I had the same issue.

Answer (score 7):

I did a global find and replace all with `,[\s]*,` and replaced it with `,`.
The double comma was found in multiple other module imports which is what was breaking my app.

Comment: brilliant! helped!

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was a missing `}` after a pipe, within an 'else' ng-template within a mat-tab:

```
<mat-tab [label]="'PHOTOS' | transloco">
  <div *ngIf="images.length; else noPhoto">
    ...
  </div>
  <ng-template #noPhoto>
    <div>
      {{ "NO_PHOTOS" | transloco } <------------------ this was the cause
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</mat-tab>
```